# Spring Boot App crashes at startup - java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

I am using EKS for the deployment of my Spring Boot App.

At startup, it crashes a couple of times, gets restarted by EKS, and finally starts serving requests.

Here are the logs: -

```html
2022-04-20 13:08:51.836  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.retry.annotation.RetryConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.retry.annotation.RetryConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e8ec2216] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-04-20 13:08:51.848  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f428cee] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-04-20 13:09:42.455 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@1248276879 - Unexpected exception while waiting for compression job to finish java.lang.InterruptedException
ERROR in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@828088650 - Unexpected exception while waiting for compression job to finish java.lang.InterruptedException
ERROR in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@1248276879 - Timeout while waiting for clean-up job to finish java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
ERROR in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@828088650 - Timeout while waiting for clean-up job to finish java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:169)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:290)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:263)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:226)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:347)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
    at com.dt.Application.main(Application.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
```

1. First two lines are warnings as per my research so far. they shouldn't cause the app to fail (let me know if I am wrong).
2. Application run failed and 4 Logback errors were printed: -

In Logback's TimeBasedRollingPolicy, there's a start() and stop() method.

When the stop() method is called, two async jobs are run. Compression job and Clean up job. The compression job threw InterruptedException and the clean-up job threw TimeoutException.

I have a few questions: -

1. I am not sure whether these Logback errors caused the app to crash or vice-versa
2. What invoked the stop() method of TimeBasedRollingPolicy
3. What interrupted the Compression job?

If you have any idea why this is happening, please let me know.

Thanks :)

Comment: Not a solution, but if you disable/remove/comment-out your logging, does the application start up correctly?  Might just help to narrow the search in case this ends up not being related to logging.

Comment: it is related to logging, verified that. when compression job throws interrupted exception, the application startup fails

Answer (score 0):

It says "Logback configuration error detected".  I would check your log configuration file to see if you have a typo in it.